# Prove that if $a$ is a real number with $a >2$, then there is an $n$ is an element of natural number such that $2+1/\sqrt{n}<a$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Prove that if $a$ is a real number with $a >2$, then there is an $n$ is an element of natural number such that $2+1/\sqrt{n}<a$

---

The goal is to show $\inf\{2+1/\sqrt{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}=2$. I started off by proving that $\{2+1/\sqrt{n}\}$ is not an empty set and $2$ is a lower bound for it.

Comment: Thanks for the link I'll definitely check the notation guide. And I just don't understand how to approach this problem. It doesn't seem like a hard problem but I've fallen behind in this class. I started off by proving that $2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is not an empty set and 2 is a lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

The square root
is just there to confuse you.
Any unbounded increasing function will do.

All that is needed is
Archimede's axiom
(AA)
for the reals:

If x and y are positive reals
then there is an integer m
such that
mx > y.

You want
$\sqrt{n}(a-2) > 1$.

Applying AA,
since $1$ and $a-2$
are positive reals,
there is an integer $m$
such that
$m(a-2) > 1$.
Now,
let $n = m^2$,
and
$\sqrt{n}(a-2) > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply solve for $n$: $$2+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < a \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} < a-2\Rightarrow \sqrt{n} > \dfrac{1}{a-2}\Rightarrow n > ....$$